# Whats the maximum speed required between server and client?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access-2010, ping

Help please,

I have an Access database with about 40 users placed around Australia, connected to a SQL server backend based in Sydney.  Performance is good most of the time but occasionally it deteriorates.  The biggest complaint from users is after updating a record is takes a second or two to move to the next line in a datasheet subform.  The setup is a master form, with a datasheet style subform for entering order lines.

I have noted when these complaints start, PING times from the local PC to the SQL Server can get above 150ms and up to 300ms, when the norm is around 30-50ms.  Is this a problem?  Is the PING time a good reference for speed?  Should 150ms still be acceptable?

My next issue is, we are wanting to move the SQL Server to the US.  It would appear the best PING times I get are around 220ms.  I have tested the connection and the lag on my forms is really bad.  Has anyone ever had to connect to a SQL Server in the US from Australia?  Can it be done?  Should I be looking at a different platform?

Any help appreciated.  Thanks.  CE.

Comment: There are many layers that need to be considered to optimize speed between server and client.
Such as: Network Layer, Application Layer, aside from Database Layer your pointing out

Comment: Using Access, which was designed from the ground up to be a single-user database, in a multi-user distributed environment is asking for trouble. It is not an "industrial strength" database. It's barely "small team" database.

Comment: Thanks Charlesliam, I am looking at the speed across the network layer only.  Ignoring database & application performance for now.  Wondering what speeds other see and if its possible to run an application over this distance.
Bohemian - the Access debate has raged for years, as a backend I would agree.  Do you have any helpful comments?